# Calling a method with List<string> Ids parameter

Tags: apex, method

I need to test a method in Developer console .

1. Method is public . So I can test from Dev Console , right?
2. Since it's a static method , I need to call `ClassName.Methodname(Parameters)`- This class should be the outermost class or the inner one?
3. Method signature is `public static List<InnerClassName> methodname(List<String> RecorIds)` - Can you please give an example of parameter?

I was calling like:

```
OuterClassName.methodname(id1,id2);
```

Can anyone please correct me?

Comment: I'm sure you are not passing two parameters instead of one.are you??

Comment: My question would be - How do I pass the List<string> as parameter to test this out?

Comment: `List<String> RecordIds =new List<String>();
    recordIds.add(id1);
    recordIds.add(id2);
    
    OuterClassName.methodname(recordIds);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<InnerClassName> innerclassList = new List<InnerClassName>();
List<String> strList = new List<String>();
strList.add(id1);
strList.add(id2);

innerclassList  =OuterClassName.methodname(strList );
```

hope this will help..

Answer (score 5):

Apex has neat collection initialization syntax (for arrays, lists, sets and maps) that allows less verbose code:

```
innerclassList = OuterClassName.methodname(new List<String>{id1, id2});
```

Better to use the `Id` type rather than the `String` type to make what is going on clearer; using the Id type also makes some [useful methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm) available.

So the call could be:

```
innerclassList = OuterClassName.methodname(new Id[]{id1, id2});
```